# How to delete Amazon s3 file w/ nodejs / angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

```
var awsSdk = require('aws-sdk');

awsSdk.config = {
  "accessKeyId": "key",
  "secretAccessKey": "secret",
  "region": "us-east-1"
}

var s3 = new awsSdk.S3({
  accessKeyId: 'key',
  secretAcessKey: 'secret'
});

exports.awsDelete = function(req, res){
  s3.deleteObject({
    Bucket: 'bucket',
    Key: req.body.photo
  }, function(err,data){
    if (err) console.log('delete err', err);
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

I can't figure out how to make this work (yet).

initially, I was getting a "no config" error, so I added the awsSdk.config json above. Now, it's just getting hung / pausing with no error. I am getting the expected key in req.body.photo.

My hunch is that i'm missing something in my config..

What am I missing / screwing up?

---

**Update**
I've added the code suggested below, but still no luck. I'll show how i'm passing my parameter:

updated code from answer below:

```
'use strict';

var aws = require('./aws');

var amazon = require('aws-sdk');

amazon.config = new amazon.Config();
amazon.config.accessKeyId = aws.key;
amazon.config.secretAccessKey = aws.secret;
amazon.config.region = aws.region;

var s3 = new amazon.S3();

exports.awsDelete = function(req, res){
  var params = {
    Bucket: aws.bucket,
    Key: res.body.photo
  };
  s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log("Successfully deleted myBucket/myKey");
 });
};
```

route:

```
  app.post('/awsDelete', uploads.awsDelete);
```

Front end Angular:

factory:

```
angular.module('clientApp').factory('Uploads', function($http) {
  return {
    delete: function(data){
        console.log('delete fired');
        return $http.post('/awsDelete', data);
    }
  };
});
```

angular controller:

```
angular.module('clientApp').controller('Distiller-editCtrl', function(Uploads){

$scope.item = {}

 $scope.delete = function(){
   Uploads.delete($scope.item).then(function(res){
    console.log(res)
    });
   };
 });
```

---

Seems it 'sort of works'. But something is making it take an extremely long time:

```
POST /awsDelete 200 120007ms
```

If I refresh the page, that causes it to successfully delete it as well. 
Does anyone notice anything in my code that could be causing such a long response time.

Also, not getting the "successfully completed" console.log

Comment: Having a similar issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this in node and it worked fine, obviously you need to put in your own accesskey, secretaccesskey, bucket and bucket key:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 

AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = "";
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "";
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {
  Bucket: 'test537658ghdfshgfd', 
  Key: '1.png'
};

s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err)     
    else console.log("Successfully deleted myBucket/myKey");   
});
```

Comment: still having issues with this. 

I do a rest call from an angular $http.post, send the key in req.body, and pass it into params (as you have above), but it keeps timing out with no error. If I refresh the page, I get a 500 error in morgan.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [Minio-Js](https://github.com/minio/minio-js) client library, its Open Source and compatible with AWS S3.

Below is remove-object.js example, you can find complete list [here](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/master/examples)

```
var Minio = require('minio')

var s3Client = new Minio({
  endPoint: 's3.amazonaws.com',
  accessKey: 'YOUR-ACCESSKEYID',
  secretKey: 'YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY'
})
// Remove an object name my-objectname.
s3Client.removeObject('my-bucketname', 'my-objectname', function(e) {
  if (e) {
    return console.log(e)
  }
  console.log("Success")
})
```

Please replace YOUR-ACCESSKEYID and YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY with your own also replace the endPoint to the one you have your bucket is created.

```
   us-east-1: 's3.amazonaws.com',
   us-west-1 : 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com',
   us-west-2 : 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
   eu-west-1: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
   sa-east-1: 's3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com',
   eu-central-1: 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
   ap-southeast-1: 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
   ap-southeast-2: 's3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
   ap-northeast-1: 's3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Installing Monio-js

```
$ npm install --save minio
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer:  I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io).